# How to build a complet circuit with the following led in left and the following circuit in the right?

Tags: circuit-analysis, led-driver

How to build a complet circuit with the following led in left and the following circuit in the right?

[image: led]
¨
[image: circuit]

Comment: you assemble the components so that the connections match the schematic

Comment: This looks like homework; please show is your work and where you get stuck. Otherwise we cannot help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit is a driver for the LED. The transistor will be working in the **saturation region** to turn on the LED (switch on 5v) and in the **cutoff region** (switch on 0v) to turn off the LED. Try the following:

- For the voltage you may use a cellphone charger.
- Use a little button for the switch.
- RB may be 10k ohm to give enough current to the base of the transistor.
- RC may be 1k ohm so your led won't blow off.

Then assemble the whole thing in a protoboard.
Also, I recommend you to read BJT theory and make circuits, lots of circuits, not only in theory but make them physically. Good luck.